# No categories in Windows Event Log

Tags: c++, windows, logging, event-log

I have created a category file to the Event Logger, but the category names do not show up in Event Logger.

If I however open the log from C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs, the category names show up. The category name also show up if I use following PowerShell.

```
$eventlog = New-Object System.Diagnostics.EventLog("MyLog")
Write-Host $eventlog.Entries[0].Category
```

The .mc file looks like this:

```
MessageIdTypedef = WORD

LanguageNames=(
    English=0x0409:MSG00409
    Swedish=0x041D:MSG0041D
)

MessageId=1
SymbolicName=CAT_1
Language=English
Category 1
.
Language=Swedish
Kategori 1
.

MessageId=2
SymbolicName=CAT_2
Language=English
Category 2
.
Language=Swedish
Kattegori 2
.

; // Up to 22 categorys
```

In the registry, I have following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\MyLog\MySource]
"CategoryCount"=dword:00000016
"TypesSupported"=dword:00000007
"CategoryMessageFile"="C:\\path\\Messages.dll"
```

I have found https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/3fed3069-ce0f-4168-8132-4d19d66fdd7e/windows-7eventlog-creating-custom-categories with the same problem, but no answer to the problem.

I have tried this in both Windows 7, 8 and Windows Server 2008 R2

**Edit**

I have created a test project to show what I have done. download it **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4g7vz653mlm6igh/EventLogTest.zip?dl=0)**

Comment: Please don't obfuscate "C:\\path\\Messages.dll", show the actual path.

Comment: Right now the Messages.dll is in the debug folder of the solution. But I have also try to move it to C:\Messages.dll.
Is it relevant for the function where the file is located in the file system?

Comment: I have created a test project. Se my edit last in my question.

Comment: @magol For information, moving the DLL in a sub folder of "Program Files (x86)" (as suggested below by Rich) solved the problem for me.

Comment: Could this be because of a bug in Wevtsvc.dll on non-english systems? There was once a hotfix 2772695 - I am not sure whether it made it into an update or not - I still see this issue on a german Windows 7 OS (in contrary to an english Windows 7 OS), and the Wevtsvc.dll is older than the one mentioned in the hotfix information.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the machine's `Authenticated Users` or `Users` group to the message folder's security level. Keep the default permissions. Then either reboot or try to restart the EventLog service.

At an administrator command prompt: `net stop eventlog`

You will likely be prompted to shutdown other services. You must enter `Y` to continue. The services being shutdown will normally restart on their own so you just need to wait a few seconds. The eventlog service may fail to shutdown because another service has restarted, it may take a couple of tries to get everything down. Watch the resulting text closely for status.

I ran into this same issue while pointing the source registry information to my message folder in my VS project. I found that it started to work after I created a `C:\Test` folder with an admin user and referenced that instead. The only difference between this and the project folder was the two groups. Adding either of the two groups made things work. Taking them both away from either folder made it stop.

I also found that if I had matching MessageId's in my `CategoryMessageFile` and my `EventMessageFile` it ignored the `CategoryMessageFile`.

Comment: You are the best! I moved my `CategoryMessageFile` to a folder in "Program Files", and BAM, I now see text in the Event viewer in the category column, instead of the infamous (n) THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, though obviously not the OP's issue (or language), that exhibits similar symptoms is when the `EventMessageFile` and the `CategoryMessageFile` have overlapping `MessageId`s. I am assuming this is a bug in the event log viewer utility when looking at a 'live' source, as the symptoms do not exist when using powershell, .NET, or directly opening the event log file in Event Viewer to parse the event logs.

In my situation, I have a .NET application and am using .NET APIs to create the event source using `EventSourceCreationData` to specify the `CategoryResourceFile` and `CategoryCount`. By default, the `MessageResourceFile` will be set to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll`. The effect of these APIs causes the creation of the [appropriate registry keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-sources) `CategoryMessageFile`, `CategoryCount`, and `EventMessageFile`. Important to note here is the message file from .NET helpfully adds messages from 0x0 to 0x000FFFF that are all defined as `%1\r\n\x00` - essentially meaning when you create an event message in the default way, using [EventLog.WriteEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.writeentry) you see the string message that was logged regardless of the event id. If instead you use [EventLog.WriteEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.writeevent), you pretty much need to use a specialized messages file (see docs on the [EventInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventinstance) class). [More Info](https://www.drdobbs.com/customizing-event-log-categories/184405714)

The symptoms are when looking at the live Event Viewer the Category as defined with the MessageId that was passed into the event log shows up as the integer instead of the string from the resource file. Note this is different behavior from if you had misconfigured the category resource file, permission issues, etc where you see the 'Task Category' as the integer but in parenthesis.

So for example, if you specified category id 8 and are expecting the localized category name 'My Category' the Event Viewer can show one of three things: `(8)` meaning the `CategoryMessageFile` or `CategoryCount` registry keys are misconfigured or there is a problem with the dll. `My Category` if everything is working as expected. `8` if you hit the issue I am describing.

Thanks to Rich Shealer's answer for the pointer. The problem is rather than getting the Category string from the `CategoryMessageFile` as one would expect, it is getting it from the `MessageResourceFile` - and since the .NET resource file merely is a formatting string that returns the first element of source data the numeric category id is generated.

There is no 'good' workaround, but in my use case of using metadata provided to log messages via a logging framework, and some filtering, messages generally have category and event id of zero, except for where I want to specifically set one when logging for a small subset of log messages. This means the logging framework is what is calling the APIs to write the log entries. A workaround is to declare MessageId of 0x0 to be `%1` in the .mc file, and only start your event ids at a number higher than the number of categories you expect to have. Then configure the `EventMessageFile` in the registry or via the property `MessageResourceFile` to first specify the category file, the semicolon delimiter, then the .NET default resource file. This will properly show and messages logged with 0's for event id and category id, and for event ids greater than your category file the same behavior you previously had. However, any eventid with a number defined that conflicts with the category - well, you get the category name as the log message. You could also remove the message resource file but then you get the annoying 'resource cannot be found' message. I confirmed the behavior here but refuse to do this - will live with the missing text, as I mostly use APIs for analysis and it is correct there.

Sadly, I can't locate any open issue with the Windows Event Viewer - I see it broken in Windows 10 build 1909.